# Low efficiency of Spark's slaves

Tags: apache-spark

I'm a spark newbie and I need advice...

I'm testing Spark's capabilities on the standalone cluster, which contains one master machine (8 CPUs, 16GB RAM)(which start `start-master.sh` and launch application) and two slave machines (both - 8 CPUs, 16GB RAM), which start `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://IP:PORT` and should use for distributed computings.
I succesfully run cluster - slaves connect to master and application works correctly.

The problem is that I don't see any efficiency in performance by comparison with running application on one local machine... As before - all CPU's of master machine are fully loaded and CPU's of slaves machines are almost inactive.
    Maybe somebody can name the typical situations - why is this happening?
    I understand, that I gave little information about my problem and configuration, but I don't know where to start and what is really important in this case.

**[Edit]**
Example code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapplication").setMaster("mastermachine:7077").setJars(new String[] {"target/myapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-driver.jar"}).set("spark.home","path_to_spark");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

...

// "Document" - is my data structure that keeps text from file

List<Document> doclist = fileNameList.stream().parallel().flatMap(docName -> Arrays.asList(getDoc(docName)).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

JavaRDD<Document> rdd = sc.parallelize(doclist);

Set<String> words = rdd.collect().stream().parallel().flatMap(doc -> doc.getWords().stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

sc.stop();
```

i.e. I'm getting strings of words from textfiles here and collect them in the Set.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in a generic way. Could you show the specific code you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the provided code, it's clear that you are not seeing any parallel distributed processing because basically Spark is not being used.

`collect`, in Spark lingo, is an action that retrieves the distributed RDD data to the driver, so when doing this:

```
// parallelize the document list to distribute over the Spark cluster
JavaRDD<Document> rdd = sc.parallelize(doclist);
// get all documents back to the driver
List<Document> docs = rdd.collect()
```

After issuing `collect`, the collection distributed in the previous step is brought back to the driver. All further operations happen on the driver and you won't see any distributed computation happening.

A correct Spark version of that code would be:

```
val docList = ???
val rdd = sc.parallelize(docList)
val wordsRdd = rdd.flatMap(doc => doc.getWords)
```

In this example, the `flatMap` function will be distributed as tasks over the cluster.

Comment: Thanx Man! I'll be more careful!

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting the answer (checkmark) if you find your question has been answered.