# How can I compute the "efficiency" in an Apache Spark application?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, processing-efficiency

I have a question regarding efficiency. In principle, I want to highlight that the only previous question on this site ([Low efficiency of Spark's slaves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000509/low-efficiency-of-sparks-slaves)) is not related to this topic.

On the other hand, I would like to know if you can explain to me how I can compute the *efficiency*, as described by **Michael J. Quinn** in his book **"Parallel Programming in C with MPI and OpenMPI"** (page **160**), in the context of Apache Spark distributed computing.

Suppose I run an algorithm with Apache Spark in a cluster consisting of 4 nodes, each with 32 cores (128 cores).

How can I compute the efficiency, if the sequential execution time is 5219 seconds and the distributed execution time is 100.36 seconds, for instance?

In this sense, what could I do to improve the efficiency?

Thanks!